# How to fix python version conflict in environment due to installed packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I am relatively new to Python. I am trying to create an env in Anaconda which includes xarray and tensorflow. xarray installs Python 3.8.5 (shown in the link), but tensorflow requires 3.6 and cannot install as a result. Can I replace the version installed with xarray?

[image: installed python version files]

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to install one of the packages with `--no-dependencies`.

Note that they may not behave exactly as expected if you do so.

Comment: Ok, I just gave something like that a shot - added '--no-deps' but still receiving an UnsatisfiableError message about the conflict.